# SUMIF and DATEDIF by row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, datediff, countif

I have a row of dates, with one date per column.  Dates are in order from oldest to newest.  I am trying to count only those where the difference is 14 days or greater.  I need it to count by row

Date A   |  Date B  |   Date C  |  Date D   |  2

So Date B - Date A = 13| Date C - Date B = 29| Date D - Date C = 15| 2

The formula should return 2, since the first was less than 14 days. 
I've spend hours on various forums with no luck.  I never post since I am usually able to figure my problems out by reading other's kind posts & suggestion.  I appreciate whatever help comes my way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B1:D1-A1:C1>=14))
```

Note the offset but same size ranges.

[image]

Comment: This is great, thank you!  How about a range where there are potential blanks at the end.  Row 1 has 10 dates and row 2 has 8 dates?

Comment: @MarkW that is a different question.  Ask a new one.  This answered this one.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a helper row, you can combine simple subtraction with a `COUNTIF()`:

[image]

So in `A2`, put `=B1-A1` and drag right.

Then in `E2`:  `=COUNTIF(A2:D2,">=14")`